# Deleting contacts in data extension - Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, automationstudio, delete

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience in using Automation Studio to delete contacts in a DE? Or, know of a better way?

Essentially what I'm looking to do, is collect data using a Cloud Page for an event. Someone will enter their details, those details are forwarded on to the relevant people and after maybe a week, those details in the DE are automatically delete from our system. This is a action requested by my compliance team.

Any recommendations and how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to delete records that have been sitting in the Data Extension for a week or so, you can use the Data Retention policy on Individual Records with specifications on the timeframe after which the record is going to be deleted.

Here are some useful links:

1. [Manage Data Retention Policy](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_manage_data_retention_policy.htm&type=5)
2. [Data Retention Policies to Existing Data Extensions in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_april_2019_cab_data_retention.htm&type=5)

Otherwise, you can add an additional `Date` datatype field with `Default Value = "Current date"`. This way once the record is populated in DE, it would get its timestamp. Next, simply run SQL within Automation Studio, which would filter out the records that are "old".

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!